# std::ofstream variable definition problems

Tags: c++, function, variables, global, ofstream

I am having problems with my ofstream variable `outfile`. I define it globally, and then try to change it within a function:

```
ofstream outfile("C:\\folder1\\folder2\\file1.file");

void a() {
    ofstream outfile("C:\\folder3\\folder4\\file2.file");
}

main(){
    a();
    outfile << "TEST";
}
```

This does not work. If I try to remove the `ofstream` in the second declaration, I get errors.

NOTE: My debugger broke

Comment: the `ofstream outfile` in the function is a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This does not work. If I try to remove the `ofstream` in the second declaration, I get errors.

Sure, there's no such `operator()` overload for `ofstream`, supposed you've been writing

```
void a() {
    outfile("C:\\folder3\\folder4\\file2.file");
}
```

Note that there's also no assignment operator defined, such writing

```
void a() {
    outfile = ofstream("C:\\folder3\\folder4\\file2.file");
}
```

can't be used either.

The closest you can get is

```
void a() {
    outfile.close();
    outfile.open("C:\\folder3\\folder4\\file2.file");
}
```

---

The real question is IMHO, why you need to declare `outfile` in the global scope. Usually it's not necessary at all.

Comment: There's no `operator()` involved, only the constructor's parameters.

Comment: @Quentin To re-cite: _"If I try to remove the `ofstream`"_.

Comment: @Quentin I guess "remove the ofstream" was understood as "change the line to `outfile("C:\\folder3\\folder4\\file2.file");`"

Comment: The `outfile.close(); outfile.open("lalala");` worked. Thanks a lot!